# Mocking objects from a constructor parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have the following class layouts:

```
public class Service {
  ServiceHelper helper;
  ...class methods...
}

public class ServiceHelper {
  Foo foo;
  Bar bar;
...class methods...
}
```

I am creating a unit test for Service, but I want to use ServiceHelper as a "live" class, but the constructor parameters inside the ServiceHelper to be mocked. Is there a way to achieve this via Mockito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your example is not a good practice. `Unit testing` should be as small as possible. The goal of unit testing is to isolate each part of the program and show that the individual parts are correct.

Anyway, you still can try this approach. I hope it helps.

```java
public class Service {

  private ServiceHelper helper;

  public Service(ServiceHelper helper) {
    this.helper = helper;
  }
}

public class ServiceHelper {

  private Foo foo;
  private Bar bar;

  // for unit testing only
  ServiceHelper(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

And the test class :

```java
public class ServiceTest {

  @Test
  public void your_test() {
    // arrange
    Foo mockedFoo = mock(Foo.class);
    Bar mockedBar = mock(Bar.class);
    ServiceHelper helper = new ServiceHelper(mockedFoo, mockedBar);  // the 'live' class
    Service service = new Service(helper);

    // act
    service.doSomething();

    // your assert ...
  }
}
```

Comment: One addendum here: we do that all the time, *but*: no "public" for those helper constructors, just keep them package protected and have a javadoc comment that says "dont use, these are for unit testing only". Just to reduce the risk of people using them in production code.

Comment: Ah you are right. So in practice, I should just mock the ServiceHelper when testing Service and mock Foo, Bar when testing ServiceHelper, right?

Comment: That is one way to go about it. Ideally, you would want to write your code to minimize the amount of mocking you need, but what is suggested here ... can work nicely.

Comment: @Rye Yes, it's better. In your case, if  production code of `ServiceHelper` occurs error, then you have to fix `ServiceTest`, too. It increases complexity in your program.